# What does the 'Battery Charger' do?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In FTL Advanced, It says:

> *"Backup Battery's lock time is halved."*

But what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just what it says, it halves the recharge time of the system '[Backup Battery](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Backup_Battery)'; it's a new system of the advanced edition.

Comment: I'm sorry, why this answer should be wrong?
You asked what Battery Charged do, and I just described that.
Battery Cahrger (http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations#Battery_Charger) halves the recharge time of the Backup Battery.
Pay attention that I linked the Backup Battery system in my response to make a reference, since it looked like you knew what Battery Charger was.

Comment: I'm sorry, u r right! apologies.